# How to resolve npm ERR! missing?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed new Windows OS in PC recently and lost all my settings. I have installed node in my system and two global npm packages. But when i am running this command `npm list -g --depth=0` or `npm list -g` then money errors are here. I have tried to install eslint but nothing resolved.

The error list is here,

```
$ npm list -g --dept=0
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- eslint@7.10.0
`-- heroku@7.43.2

npm ERR! missing: @babel/code-frame@^7.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: eslint-scope@^5.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: eslint-visitor-keys@^1.1.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: espree@^6.1.2, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: esquery@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: esutils@^2.0.2, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: functional-red-black-tree@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: ignore@^4.0.6, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: import-fresh@^3.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: imurmurhash@^0.1.4, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: levn@^0.3.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: natural-compare@^1.4.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: progress@^2.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: regexpp@^2.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: table@^5.2.3, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: text-table@^0.2.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: v8-compile-cache@^2.0.3, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: fast-deep-equal@^2.0.1, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: fast-json-stable-stringify@^2.0.0, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: json-schema-traverse@^0.4.1, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: uri-js@^4.2.2, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: esutils@^2.0.2, required by doctrine@3.0.0
npm ERR! missing: eslint-visitor-keys@^1.1.0, required by eslint-utils@1.4.3
npm ERR! missing: flatted@^2.0.0, required by flat-cache@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.6.3, required by flat-cache@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: type-fest@^0.8.1, required by globals@12.3.0
npm ERR! missing: cli-width@^2.0.0, required by inquirer@7.0.0
npm ERR! missing: emoji-regex@^8.0.0, required by string-width@4.1.0
npm ERR! missing: deep-is@~0.1.3, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: levn@~0.3.0, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: prelude-ls@~1.1.2, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: type-check@~0.3.2, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: word-wrap@~1.2.3, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: @babel/code-frame@^7.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: eslint-scope@^5.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: eslint-visitor-keys@^1.1.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: espree@^6.1.2, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: esquery@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: esutils@^2.0.2, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: functional-red-black-tree@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: ignore@^4.0.6, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: import-fresh@^3.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: imurmurhash@^0.1.4, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: levn@^0.3.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: natural-compare@^1.4.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: progress@^2.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: regexpp@^2.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: table@^5.2.3, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: text-table@^0.2.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: v8-compile-cache@^2.0.3, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: fast-deep-equal@^2.0.1, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: fast-json-stable-stringify@^2.0.0, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: json-schema-traverse@^0.4.1, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: uri-js@^4.2.2, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: esutils@^2.0.2, required by doctrine@3.0.0
npm ERR! missing: eslint-visitor-keys@^1.1.0, required by eslint-utils@1.4.3
npm ERR! missing: mimic-fn@^2.1.0, required by onetime@5.1.0
npm ERR! missing: emoji-regex@^8.0.0, required by string-width@4.1.0
npm ERR! missing: flatted@^2.0.0, required by flat-cache@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.6.3, required by flat-cache@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: type-fest@^0.8.1, required by globals@12.3.0
npm ERR! missing: deep-is@~0.1.3, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: levn@~0.3.0, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: prelude-ls@~1.1.2, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: type-check@~0.3.2, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: word-wrap@~1.2.3, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: chai@^4.1.2, required by nock@9.6.1
npm ERR! missing: deep-equal@^1.0.0, required by nock@9.6.1
npm ERR! missing: json-stringify-safe@^5.0.1, required by nock@9.6.1
npm ERR! missing: propagate@^1.0.0, required by nock@9.6.1
npm ERR! missing: qs@^6.5.1, required by nock@9.6.1
```

**How can i get a clean window without error? and How to resolve all these error?**

Comment: try doing npm rebuild or npm install

Comment: not resolved, any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by manually installing the same version of the missing packages as global.